# Как строятся справочные системы?

Tags: sql, база-данных, алгоритм, словари

Имеется какой-то справочник на N адресов к которому обращается многопользователей.

Казалось бы, размещай справочник в СУБД и все...

Но, обычно, справочные системы предлагают поиск по частичному совпадению => от пользователей идет множество LIKE запросов, которые СУБД не может оптимизировать так как индексы не работают.

Вот как выходят из такой ситуации? Неужели все решает покупкой более мощного железа?

Comment: Если поиск идет по началу или концу строки, то индексы очень даже работают например в Оракле. То есть запросы вида `like '%text'` и `like 'text%` вполне себе работают по индексам.  В дополнение справочники обычно не очень большие, и поиск даже без индексов работает быстро

Comment: @lDrakonl, да. Про это я знаю. Но если искать с середины слова, то индексы уже не работают.

Comment: Используйте полнотекстовый поиск. Может быть встроен прямо в субд или быть отдельным приложением. И вообще, кто-то забивает буквы в компьютер с середины слова? Может при этом ещё и в обратном порядке, от середины к началу, потом от конца к середине? Такое тоже надо предусмотреть. Обязательно!

Comment: @iluxa1810 все еще зависит от самого справочника. Размер, распределение данных. Не всегда полный скан таблицы хуже доступа по индексу.  Возможно дело вообще не в лайках по тексту, а чем то другом.

Comment: Я бы не ограничивался использованием RDBMS. Почитайте о ElasticSearch (или SOLR) и Hadoop (в качестве платформы)...

Comment: Можно использовать внешний поисковый движок, например, Sphinx. Если нужна актуальность данных в разрезе секунды, например, можно при добавлении данных добавлять строку в индекс сфинкса

Answer (score 2):

Есть **N-граммный поиск**. Он воспринимает строку как набор отдельных подстрок длины N, а показателем релевантности служит число таких подстрок, общих между документом и поисковым запросом.

Такой подход позволяет обнаруживать мелкие опечатки в словах или находить слова только по кусочку сколько-нибудь существенной (от N+1) длины.

Реализаций достаточно, есть выбор.

---

Есть [N-граммный токенизатор в ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html). Есть [и в Apache Solr](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers#Tokenizers-N-GramTokenizer). В Sphinx N-граммный поиск [можно включить](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-ngram-len.html) (утверждается, что он имеет смысл для корейского, японского и китайского, где беда с разделением на слова).

Как видно, есть практически во всех известных поисковых серверах, и если вам нужен действительно мощный поиск, лучше воспользоваться разработанным специально для этой цели продуктом. Покопавшись в инструкциях к выбранному, можно найти и другие алгоритмы, которые, возможно, вам понравятся больше.

---

А теперь что-нибудь менее обычное.

Для PostgreSQL имеется модуль **триграммного поиска** ([`pg_trgm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgtrgm.html)). Как можно догадаться, это N-граммный поиск, где N=3.

Для него практически необходим отдельный индекс GIN или GiST, составленный по классу операторов из этого модуля. GIN довольно большой по объёму, не слишком быстро обновляется, но быстр для поиска; тогда как GiST компактнее и быстрее обновляется, но может давать ложные совпадения. Поэтому для редко обновляемых данных GIN оптимальнее.

Это неплохой вариант, если у вас уже используется PostgreSQL, он не особенно нагружен (или есть возможность это обеспечить) и от поиска не нужна большая интеллектуальность.

*У него есть и [реализация полнотекстового поиска](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch.html), но это уже не относится к N-граммному.*

Comment: N-граммный поиск предназначен для нечеткого поиска (когда нужно избавиться от дублей с опечатками, например, или искать все более или менее похожие варианты). Для точного поиска по справочнику его использование сомнительно.

Comment: @minamoto как раз для адресов этот поиск подходит очень неплохо, т. к. топонимы в адресах пользователи частенько вводят с некоторыми отклонениями, на букву-другую. А свой ответ зря стёрли. Понимать, почему решение плохое, тоже полезно. Но дело ваше, разумеется.

Comment: Про отклонения в адресах на букву-другую есть смешной анекдот:
"xxx: все, я приехал, я на ленинградском вокзале
xxx: я взял такси, напомни адрес
yyy: ул. паперника, дом xx
xxx: вот жеж вы москвачи со своим олбанским
xxx: коперника улица, коперника
xxx: николай коперник, польский ученый, великий астроном, а вы его так, эх, не стыдно?
yyy: точно, езжай уже туда"